# asp.net mvc accessing class fields from a custom auth attribute

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I am using a custom AuthAttribute to determine whether a user can access a controller and/or actions.  The problem is I have to duplicate information and EFx connections in the attribute that already exist on the class that is being adorned.

My question is whether there is a way to access the fields on the adorned class from the custom AuthAttribute?  I am trying to avoid having to re-architect the software in a way that would provide a single point of access since that would open up a different can of worms.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found *an* answer that works.  I welcome all comments on this solution.

Rather than have the attribute gain access to the properties and fields on the controller it adorns you can share values between them in a thread-safe way through the common HttpContext object.  So if you are being extreme like I am and are trying to cut down on duplicate calls to your database in both the authattribute and the adorned controller action then pass the results forward.  What that means is the authattribute will be called first and you can stash the retrieved values in the "Items" collection off the HttpContext object passed into the AuthorizeCore(..) method.  You can then retrieve the same value in a THREAD-SAFE way through the HttpContext object in the controller.

example to save value within the AuthorizeCore(..) override of the AuthAttribute:

```
httpContext.Items.Add("fester", "bester");
```

example to retrieve value inside the subsequent call to the Controller/Action:

```
this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context.Items["fester"];
```

I have to warn you this is only a possible implementation that appears to work in simple testing.  Personally it feels like a hack and there has to be a better way.  I would also state this is in pursuit of a dubious performance benefit.  It should cut down on the number of database and/or network calls by cache'ing retrieved data in the HttpContext so you don't have to repeat the calls in both the authattribute and the adorned Controller/Action.  If you don't have a web site that gets a huge volume of calls then I would warn you against this.

I hope someone recommends something better on this page.  I will keep an eye on how this works on my web site and let y'all know if it behaves and is truly thread-safe.